# Gradle - Dependency propagation from jar

Tags: java, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a jar that has 2 dependencies. I have a war that includes that jar as a dependency. I found that I have to also include the 2 dependencies of the jar in my war build.gradle file.

In my experience with Maven, I wouldn't have to do this. I explored the fat jar option but that includes ALL the dependencies and the jar is rather large.

How can I configure my war/jar build.gradle files to propagate the 2 jars without defining them explicitly in my war application?

Edit:
Adding my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>s3-ftp-adapter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.9</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ftpserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>ftpserver-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.69</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Well, how did you publish the jar in the repository? What is its associated pom?

Comment: The jar gets deployed to artifactory via jenkins. There is no pom, as I haven't created one. This is where my confusion stems from. I understand how dependency management works in maven and half expected it to work in the same manner with gradle. It does make sense that I'd need a pom, but I haven't experienced that with gradle.

Comment: You need to generate a pom. There is no other way for gradle (or Maven), to know about the dependencies of your jar file. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html for how to generate a pom and publish an artifact (and its pom) with gradle.

Comment: When I update my project to use the new version, it still doesn't appear to resolve these dependencies. The gradle dependencies cli command also shows that they're not being included.